How to reset Debezium offset to start streaming from different DB server after migration
We are using Debezium connectors to stream PostgreSQL data into kafka. We will have a major version upgrade on PostgreSQL(13 to 16) by side by side approach using logical replication to new server. After the upgrade we would like to continue streaming to kafka without reinitialising the data using snapshot. If I simply change connector properties to new server it will search for a WAL position to resume which is not available in new server.
Is there any way to reset offset or WAL position in debezium to follow new server and start streaming afterwards ?

Debezium stores metadata in kafka. Sure, you could manually produce a new event to override its information. Example https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/

This can be achieved by renaming or creating a new connector and specifying snapshot.mode="never". Offset works based on connector name.
